# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'

Tags: sql, sql-server

My application is generating this query.Can someone please tell what is wrong with the query

```
     SELECT task_id, 
     Count(*) Unread 
     FROM   discussion 
     WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                        FROM   discussion_read 
                        WHERE  discussion.discussion_id = 
                        discussion_read.discussion_id 
                        AND discussion_read.user_id = ? 
                        AND discussion.task_id IN 
                          ((SELECT TOP 1025 task.task_id 
                            FROM   task 
                            WHERE 
                          ( ( task.task_code = 'A3090' ) 
                            AND ( task.proj_id = 6511 ) )) 
                                                 ORDER  BY task.task_id ASC) 
              ) 
    GROUP  BY task_id
```

Comment: I was getting this error when trying to save my view, using a query that executes just fine. My friend told me that you can't use ORDER BY for a view query - i suppose that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your order by need to be inside `)` try below

```
SELECT task_id, 
 Count(*) Unread 
 FROM   discussion 
 WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                    FROM   discussion_read 
                    WHERE  discussion.discussion_id = 
                    discussion_read.discussion_id 
                    AND discussion_read.user_id = ? 
                    AND discussion.task_id IN 
                      ((SELECT TOP 1025 task.task_id 
                        FROM   task 
                        WHERE 
                      ( ( task.task_code = 'A3090' ) 
                        AND ( task.proj_id = 6511 ) ) 
                                             ORDER  BY task.task_id ASC)) 
          ) 
GROUP  BY task_id
```

Comment: @BarbC.Goldstein : It is necessary because of using `TOP` keyword in the select query. `Top ` without `Order By` retuns random `top 25` rows

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
 SELECT task_id, 
 Count(*) Unread 
 FROM   discussion 
 WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                    FROM   discussion_read 
                    WHERE  discussion.discussion_id = 
                    discussion_read.discussion_id 
                    AND discussion_read.user_id = ? 
                    AND discussion.task_id IN 
                      (SELECT TOP 1025 task.task_id   --Remove Extra braces
                        FROM   task 
                        WHERE 
                        task.task_code = 'A3090' 
                        AND  task.proj_id = 6511 
                        ORDER  BY task.task_id ASC -- It should be for Select Top statement
                        ) 

          ) 
GROUP  BY task_id
```